# Host unreachable admin prohibited

Tags: java, sockets, server, icmp

Hi I wrote a simple chat server, which will forward the data between two clients. I run the server in a PUBLIC IP (OS Fedora), but when I am trying to connect with the listening port I am getting error "Host unreachable admin prohibited" (I used wireshark to capture the error).

Can anybody say, what's going on here. A public IP should not be unreachable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A public IP is unreachable when a firewall has a restriction on ICMP traffic, which many do.  https://unixspace.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/35/comment-page-1/

Comment: Thanks I did not know that.